# Session not getting from uiwebview in ios

Tags: ios, session, google-drive-api

I am trying to get session from `UIWebView` but not getting any idea for that. Consider following case:

1. I am logging into google drive from `UIWebView`
2. Now I want to get that logged in session or other information for check I am already logged in or not on google drive in my application

Any one have idea about that ?

Comment: Thank you nmh. But is there any idea to download files from google drive using UIWebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does not support using web views on iOS. Please use the [Google Drive iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart) for a supported method.